# NoSuchElementException in method next() Java

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

The purpose of the method `removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Card> l)` is that removing the duplicated object based on the attribute `card_value` in class `Card` and then add them to an ArrayList and return the arr.

But my program return an error: `NoSuchElementException` at the line

`dum.add((Card) it.next());`

I have no idea what's going on here because I print out the object that returned by the `next()` method, it prints out perfectly.

Someone please show me why I get mistake in the implementation below:

```
private ArrayList<Card> removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Card> l){
    int end = l.size();
    Set<Card> set = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
        set.add(l.get(i));
    }
    ArrayList<Card> dummy = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
        dummy.add((Card) it.next());
    }

    return dummy;
}
```

And these are override methods:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.card_value;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Card)){
            return false;
        }
        Card other = (Card) obj;
        return (this.card_value == other.card_value);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `.next()` twice. `next()` fetches the next element in the iterator but you only check `hasNext()` before the first one.

Change

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
    dummy.add((Card) it.next());
}
```

to

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    Card nextCard = (Card) it.next();
    System.out.println(nextCard);
    dummy.add(nextCard);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java?av=h#AbstractList.Itr) you can see the source code of the [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) method from java [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). It looks something like this:

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    try {
        int i = cursor;
        E next = get(i);
        lastRet = i;
        cursor = i + 1;
        return next;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        checkForComodification();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you are out of the array a [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) will be thrown. So calling `next()` twice without checking before each call if elements are still available by using `hasNext()` will have the behaviour you described.

Your `while()` should be replaced with:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    dummy.add((Card) it.next());
}
```

But if you really want the print-out as you have it, just change it to:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Card card = (Card)it.next();
    System.out.println(card);
    dummy.add(card);
}
```

The second approach is the better way to go when you need to use an object more than once in a method or loop if the method called may be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

`It.next()` returns the next item.

What you do in your code is calling it.next() twice

Answer (score 0):

because next() moves on the pointer each time, so when you print it out, it will print the last one, then try to move on again the line after